# Save lines that are not in regex python

Tags: python, regex

My actual code, is writing in a new file, the data from the regex.
At the end, I have a new file with some isolated lines.

```
contract_data = []
with open('output/'+contract, "r") as f: 
    contents = f.read()

    m = re.search("PAS_BEGIN_"+ contract_id +"([\S\s]*)PAS_END_"+ contract_id, contents)

    if m:
        contract_data.append(m.group())

    with open('output/'+contract, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in contract_data:
            outfile.write(line)
```

What I want to do, is to get everything from the file minus what I capture from the regex.

I have read avec reverse regex, but I was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do so.

Any help is appreciated

Regards

Comment: you want everything which is not captured in the regex ?

Comment: Exactly yes, I have tried negative regex, but didn't work..

Comment: Can you please edit you question with what are you matching with regex. So, Basically what is the input what output you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code - <s>for starters, if you want to discriminate line by line, you should read and process your file line by line</s>. Also, it's generally not a good idea to open a file for writing before closing it for reading. Lastly, instead of inverting your pattern, you can use `re.sub()` to remove the parts matching it.

Thus:

```
with open("output/" + contract, "r") as f:  # open for reading
    contract_data = re.sub("PAS_BEGIN_" + contract_id + r"([\S\s]*)PAS_END_" + contract_id,
                           "", f.read())

with open("output/" + contract, "w") as f:  # open for writing
    f.write(contract_data)
```

Comment: @vieroli - Then your regex is wrong. The above will write only the lines that do not match your regex. Also, why are you using `[\S\s]` character class, use a dot (`.`) instead as it will match everything, too.

Comment: @vieroli - That makes things far clearer, check the update above.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('output/'+contract, "r") as f: 
    contents = f.read().splitlines()


 with open('output/'+contract, 'w') as outfile:
     for line in contents:
        if not "PAS_BEGIN_"+ contract_id +"([\S\s]*)PAS_END_"+ contract_id in line:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.